# Getting text from table row with beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'd like to extract the text from between the  tags with beautiful soup. So far I have:

```
def table_to_text(html):
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    trs = soup.findAll('tr')
    for tr in trs:
        print 'row '
        print tr.findAll(['td','th']).text
```

This gives me output that looks like:

```
row 
[<td> AAA </td>, <td>Chi</td>, <td></td>, <td class="center"><span class="blue">1353</span>/<span class="red">23</span></td>]/n
```

I'd like to get the output to look like:

```
[ AAA , Chi, , 1353, 23]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.findAll` returns a list so you need another for loop like this:

```
[el.text for el in sp.find_all(['td', 'th']) if el.text]
```

Comment: Thank you very much that works! Can I ask what is the difference between findAll and find_all?